# Email bounce management in apex?

Tags: apex, email

I have bounce management turned on in my org, and email bounces are detected when messages are sent using the Mass Email wizard, but they aren't detected when messages are sent through apex. Is there any way to flag invalid email addresses on contacts when the messages are sent through apex?